# Product prices should visible after entering username and password as like admin panel

Tags: price, register, addtocart

If we visit magento site, Products "prices" or "add to cart button"[optional either one] should not visible on entire site[on product list page, product view page, featured products , everywhere.] after entering username and password only customers can see the products prices.  [as like in admin panel login, but USername: & password box: should be on home page] ,

Please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, You have to place the add to cart code in the

```
if($sessionCustomer->isLoggedIn())
{
  <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button    btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
}
```

in **list.phtml**

Then in **View.phtml**

```
if($sessionCustomer->isLoggedIn())
{
  <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
}
```

Try this code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code. Check whether the customer is logged in or not

**List page**

```
$sessionCustomer = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
if($sessionCustomer->isLoggedIn()) 
{
echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
}
```

**View page**

```
$sessionCustomer = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

if($sessionCustomer->isLoggedIn()) 
{
    echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data');
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks @Manikandan Can you please explain answer in details with where  i have to place the code in list.phtml and view.phtml

Comment: In list.phtml and view.phtml you can find a class name "product-shop" in there you can apply this codes

Comment: Hi, I did changes as you told in following links. Please inform if there is any changes i have to do.

list.phtml http://pastebin.com/puh5PdQM

view.phtml http://pastebin.com/1Bk6bwta

Comment: no more codes to update. It's enough

Comment: you have wrongly placed the codes. You have the replace the code in list.phtml line 64 & view.phtml line 65

Comment: Okay , i will change now.

Comment: Hi, Please check list .phtml = > http://pastebin.com/bMPkJBA4 view.phtml = > http://pastebin.com/cHy7Jbkv

Comment: I think i did some wrong i am getting Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object

Comment: Both links are the same list.phtml. you want to replace this code <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?> with my code. in same as view.phtml <?php  echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data'); ?> replace my code

Comment: Hi, sorry for that wrong code, now please check : list.phtml = >http://pastebin.com/DmemG62Q view.phtml = >

http://pastebin.com/xXf4hCYm It helpmed to remove price in product view page, but its still visible in Products list page and checkout page

Comment: As my problem is to hide price before login, after login it should visible . so how i can do that?

Comment: you will find the same line: 104 <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?> you want to replace that too. Then you redirect the checkout page if customer not logged in

Comment: Hi, you are genius, i removed the prices on both catalog view page and product list page, now i edited the question, please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16299/discussion-between-manikandan-and-user3483987).

Comment: yes, It's better to remove add to cart only, but the add to cart button should visible only after entering username and password. how i can do that.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use one of the B2B extension available in the market. Below i have pasted the link of one of the free extension [Sitewards B2B](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sitewards-b2b-professional.html)

It will cover your requirement well and you won't need to play dirty around code.

NOTE : This is a free extension and i am not in any way related with the ext developer. I have used it in one of the website and suggesting it from my experience